# Computing Expectation of Ball Drawing Problem

Tags: probability

You have in a bag 6 different toys corresponding to 6 different shapes. You pick and replace a toy each time in the bag. What is the expected number of times you will have to pick and replace toys before having picked the 6 different toys?

Comment: This is known as the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)? Short answer, $6*\sum_{i=1}^61/i$ or $n*H_n$, where $H_n$ is the $nth$ [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thanks! I just checked out the Coupon Collector's Problem. So this expectation may not be an integer, right?

Comment: No. In fact, I don't think it's an integer for any value above $n=1$.